# Authenticating to cloud function from PubSub push subscription

Tags: google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub

We are using PubSub for queuing utilizing a push subscription pointing at an **http-triggered** cloud function. According to [this](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/push#and) documentation Cloud Run and App Engine will both authenticate requests from PubSub, cloud functions isn't listed. We have used other google services, like scheduler to invoke functions which require authentication, but have not had luck doing so with PubSub.

My question is, does cloud functions support authentication from PubSub through a subscription aim account set, or is it required that the function read and deal with the JWT itself for authentication?

Comment: Yes, it supports. Can you share your push subscription configuration?

Comment: The subscription is set basically as @Ricco's answer is below. I have tried different levels of service accounts with no success. Monitoring always shows 401 results for the subscription.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need different things:

- A service account with the role/cloudfunctions.invoker
- tick the `Enable authentication`
- Select your service account
- **Add the Cloud Function URL (as provided in the Cloud Function) in the audience field.** *It's the missing part in the Ricco answer*

[image]

---

**EDIT 1**

PubSub needs to have the authorization to generate a token on a service account. Check the [first step on this](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/tutorials/pubsub#integrating-pubsub). There, it shows how to grant the pubsub service agent service account as token creator.

Comment: Yes I have all of that and still it doesn't authenticate. There must be something else going on. And I do know the process works as I reinstalled the function with `--allow-authenticated` and everything worked as expected. So it is a permissions configuration thing I am assuming.

Comment: 401 is unauthorized: your authentication works, but you haven't the permission.

Comment: Deleted and recreated subscription with different name. same result 401, auth_required. I used a service account with owner with the same result . I will try again with a temp service account with owner permissions.

Comment: Deleted and recreated the subscription using a service account with owner rights and get the same result, 401, auth required. I find it a bit concerning that this, https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/push#and, doesn't mention functions at all. I have successfully invoked functions from cloud scheduler. I really don't have a clue why it isn't working from PubSub. Maybe I just move the function to Cloud Run. Though I was hoping to keep a function

Comment: I had this a time. Check my edit, it should be a problem on PubSub permissions

Comment: I was prompted to grant permissions for the PubSub account to generate tokens and allowed it.

Comment: Thank you @guillaume for all the time you have spent with me and working through this. The issue in this case was the audience string. I was using the same string as the end-point which is a longer path than the trigger defined on the function. This should be a good reference for someone in the future.

Comment: It's to work with functions.https.onRequest(...), right? How can I check in my function if the auth is ok?

Answer (score 2):

Pub/Sub subscription supports the use of service account authentication for subscriptions using "Push".

To use service accounts just specify the endpoint of the cloud function, enable authentication and add a service account to be used to send requests to the cloud function. Make sure that the service account has the appropriate permissions to access both PubSub and cloud functions.

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Ricco, so I did this, even added an owner service account and still receive access denied (401). From what I understand the service account used only requires cloudfunction.invoke to be able to invoke the function. Any suggestions? Which PubSub permissions would be required for the service account? I am assuming the service setup would be the same that would be used for Cloud Run.

Comment: The issue with this answer is that it doesn't include the needed audience string for the authentication to work correctly.

Comment: Thank you! That really solves my problem. I had to enable 3 permissions:
Cloud Functions Invoker, 
Cloud Run Invoker, 
Pub/Sub Publisher